# Elixir: recompile on config update

Tags: elixir

I have an elixir app, and when I update the app config e.g. change the port and then run my app again, I don't see any difference. It seems that the app still works with the old version on the config. And I have to amend the app code (for example add some meaningless line: IO.put("foo")) and only after that, the app runs with the new version of the config. What is the true way to accomplish the same result ?

Comment: I have found this when running mix tasks (not the actual app), i have to run `mix compile` first.

Comment: Note: if you have custom tasks, it is their responsibility to call `mix compile` if they depend on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix should [recompile the project if you change any file inside "config"](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/ce15d018d8f38fdf9dfe6010fd8e91614305ab05/lib/mix/lib/mix/project.ex#L199-L230).

My guess is that you may be invoking a custom task that does not ask your project to compile. It is the responsibility of every Mix task to say which state they expect the application to be: compiled, loaded, etc.

Comment: I use mix run --no-halt task, and i don't see any changes when i amend my configs inside "config" folder

Comment: What is your Elixir version? Can you push a sample project that reproduces the issue to GitHub? I will gladly take a look at it.

Comment: I use Elixir 1.5.3 I will add a link to an example project soon.

Comment: You were right, I tried again and everything works as you describe. I don't know why i didn't work before. Sorry to disturb you(

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce this behavior, probably due to more recent `mix` version. Below is a blind guess what might cause it and how to overcome it.

There is a significant difference between `.exs` files ans `.ex` files in Elixir. The former is so-called “Elixir script,” the latter is generic Elixir file that is to be compiled.

`mix` tool is looking for changes *in files to be compiled* before executing [`run`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Run.html#content) task.

Since `.exs` files are treated as *scripts*, `mix` does not consider the project has changed and requires re-compilation. Luckily enough, `run` task accepts `--config` command line option, that allows to explicitly specify what config file to use. When config is explicitly specified, it will be force-reloaded and new values will explicitly take an effect.